Boot partition too small
My disk looks like this:



Partition
Filesystem
Size
% Full




EFI
FAT32
537M
1.4


BOOT
ext4
256M
42.2


LVM
Linux LVM
999G




The boot partition is now too small to do a kernel upgrade, even after using all the usual tricks.
I am proposing to shrink the almost unused EFI partition and then enlarge the boot partition to the left so should not be affected.
Is this likely to cause problems? I will of course do a backup first. My thinking is that the boot sector will be at the beginning of the EFI partition so should be undisturbed.
The system boots with EFI

Should work, the efi bootloaders are just files, no more sector nonsense to worry about. I've used 100MB EFI partitions when space was tight.  Check the partition/filesystem UUIDs after changing partitions -- they may be changed with a resize and things like EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg and /etc/fstab may need new UUIDs.

Ubuntu's installer now uses a default /boot partition size of 1.67 GiB. Be advised that I wasn't able to update the kernel with a stripped down 732.00 MiB /boot. Also, if your LVM is encrypted, you won't be able to shift the left side - unfortunately.
